# OpenLayers default zoom level

Tags: javascript

I have a map setup with [Openlayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers/) and [mapbox](http://drupal.org/project/mapbox). I need to set the default zoom level to be in-between 1 and 2. So something like 1.5, as 2 is too zoomed in and 1 is too zoomed out.

I have entered different values under 'zoom level' within 'center & bounds', but only whole numbers seems to have an effect on the map.

Does anyone know of a way to set a default zoom level that is not a whole number? So something like 1.5 ?

I am using Drupal 7.

Thanks you help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that, I think the Zoom level has to be an INT.
Basically there is as many tiles'size as the number of zoom available.
That means there is no tiles available for a float value, otherwise it will require too many tiles to have a map not fuzzy.